# How to move add button above listing for inline entity form

Tags: 8, hooks

We're using Inline Entity Form for a project and we have a bunch nested content types.

For one of those content types, we want the add button to be above the listing of existing entities of that type ... how can we do that cleanly?

I could probably just cut and paste the button using jQuery but there has to be a way to do this using hooks but I haven't found the right one yet ... any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: Visual explanation of what I'm trying to do]